# Speeding up "Tasks" > "Import Data..." in SQL Server 2012 (indexes and file growth)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm copying 99 million rows from one SQL Server instance to another using the right-click "Tasks" > "Import Data" method.  It's just a straight copy into a new, empty table on a new and empty NDF file.  I'm using the identity insert when doing the copy so that the IDs will stay in tact.  It was going very slowly (30 million records after 12 hours), so my boss told me to cancel it, remove all indexes from the new empty table, then run again.

1. Will removing indexes on the new table really speed up the transfer of records, and why?  I imagine I can create indexes after the table is filled.
2. What is the underlying process behind right-click "Import Data"?  Is it using SqlBulkCopy, is it logging tons of stuff?  I know it's not in a transaction because cancelling it stopped it immediately and the already inserted rows were there.
3. My file growth on the NDF file that holds the table is 20MB.  Will increasing this speed up the process when using the above records on 99 million records?  It's just an idea I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it should. Each new row being inserted will cause each index to be updated with the new data. It's worth noting that if you remove the indexes, import, then re-add the indexes, those indexes will take a very long time to build anyway.
2. It essentially runs as a very simple SSIS package. It reads rows from the source and inserts in chunks as a transaction. If your recovery model is set to Full, you could switch it to Bulk Logged for the import. This should be done if you're bulk-moving data when other updates to the database won't be happening, though.
3. I would try to size the MDF/NDF close to what you'd expect the end result to be. The autogrowth can take time, especially if you have it set low.